# Frame around entire document

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, templates

I am trying to put a tcolorbox around my entire document (each page). I am going through Math Partner's Tutorial on Youtube and put all the code in correctly, but there is no box spanning my page.  The code is below, does anyone have any ideas as to why the frame is not working?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=12mm,right=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}

%reformat question and parts 
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\textbf{\thequestion).}}
\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\textbf{\thepartno).}}



\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[%
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        frame hidden,
        overlay broken={
            \draw[line width=0.5mm, gray,rounded corners]
            (frame.north west)rectangle (frame.south east);},
        colback=white,height fixed for=all]{}
            

\pointsdroppedatright
\marginpointname{ \points}
\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{25mm}
\pointformat{\bfseries\boldmath[\themarginpoints]}
    \begin{questions}
        \question[4]Find the equation of the tangent to the curve $y=4x^2-5x+7$ \droppoints
            
            \vspace*{1in}
                \answerline
                
                
                
        
                \rule{\textwidth}{1.25pt}
        \question[2] Expand $(x-2)(x+3)$ \droppoints
            \vspace*{1in}
        
        \question Solve 
            \begin{parts}
                \part[2] $3(x-2)=1$ \droppoints
                    \vspace*{1in}
                \part[4] $5x-4=\frac{1}{2}$ \droppoints
            \end{parts}

\question Simplify 
    \end{questions}
    
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: `frame hidden` hides the frame. Comment it out.

Comment: Thank you! Works nicely!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.